# Change background-color Cell in Datagrid (Flex 4.6)

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, flexbuilder

I'm trying to alternate between two background colors for each cell in a datagrid. It changes its state upon double clicking in a particular cell.

What I want is that the user be able to select individuals cell in a Datagrid so #FFFFFF color is for unselected cells and #CDCDCD for selected ones.

I have the following code for an ItenRenderer:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                    clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
                //lblData.text = data[column.dataField]
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="selected"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" text="10" width="100%" height="100%" textAlign="center"/>
    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color.selected="#CDCDCD" color.normal="#FFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

The question is that label is never shown due to the rect component hide it. how can i accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to position the text? Maybe you need some kind of layout?

Comment: the text center align in vertical and horizontal position, and link the label text to the data from the grid cell.

Comment: So you want the text to be on top of the colored rectangle?

Comment: My goal is to be able to select individual cells. So, when double checked, the cell change it's background color to light-grey. Now I could show the text over the background.

Comment: Try adding them both to a <s:Group> and reverse the order of the <s:Rect> and <s:Label>

Comment: Ok, and how can I show the value from headerText in the itemRenderer to set it in the Label? I tried with ...text="{data.label}"... and no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

//Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]private var initDG:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Artist:'01', Album:'Album 01', Year:'2008'},
            {Artist:'02', Album:'Album 02', Year:'2009'},
            {Artist:'03', Album:'Album 03', Year:'2007'},
            {Artist:'04', Album:'Album 04', Year:'2003'},
        ]);
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup>
    <s:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="360" dataProvider="{initDG}">   
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="Artist" headerText="Artist" itemRenderer="com.dgcoloredcells.CellRenderer"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="Album" headerText="Album" itemRenderer="com.dgcoloredcells.CellRenderer"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="Year" headerText="Year" itemRenderer="com.dgcoloredcells.CellRenderer"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>       
    </s:DataGrid> 
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

//Renderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
        import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;

        private var _listData:BaseListData;

        [Bindable]private var isSelected:Boolean = false;

        override public function set data( value:Object ) : void 
        {
            super.data = value;
            lblData.text = data[column.dataField];
        }

        [Bindable]public function get listData() : BaseListData
        {
            return _listData;
        }
        public function set listData( value:BaseListData ) : void
        {
            _listData = value;
        }

        private function onClick(evt:Event):void
        {
            isSelected = !isSelected;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="{isSelected ? 0xCDCDCD : 0xFFFFFF}"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" width="100%" height="100%" textAlign="center" doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="onClick(event)"/>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

**//EDIT**
Here you can see my screenshot for data[column.dataField] problem:

[image]

Here is the coresponding value object

[image]

So data[column.dataField] = data["Artist"] = "01"

Comment: Hi Anton, which release of Flex SDK you use? That code raise an error in line "lblData.text = data[column.dataField];" indicating null object. What could be the problem? I have 4.6.

Comment: Hi, I use Flash Builder 4.6, sdk 4.6.0. Try to diagnose the problem by means of debug. What do you see in your column.dataField? I will now post a screenshot into my answer.

Comment: I ca not post images already. I have just upload an image to my server: http://www.apalabrados.co/flex/debug_capture.png

Comment: Would you send me your project files to the email address from my profile? Or post screenshots from both mxml on your server. It is strange to see "listData = null"

Comment: It is complecated for me to check the process without all valueObjects and so on. I would do two things. First af all I would try to create a project with my two files. So we could see if it is sdk problem or code error. Secondly I would try to see if your data can be shown in a normal datagrid without renderer or not. And you should add implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer" to your renderer head.

Comment: Hi Anton, at least I discovered the problem. I added the following line if (value != null)
     lblData.text = data[column.dataField]; and works fine. Now I have a doubt. When a cell is selected, how can i get access such info from the main MXML?

Comment: Fine! I would just add a new field to your dataprovider and change it in the renderer when the doublclick happens. If the field is called "isselected" then you just write the value to data.isselected.